# get date without any symbol

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the data which should not show data before current date. But the problem is, the date that is stored in the table is in int format. If in it January 23 2012 then the date format in my table is 20130123. But the curdate() function will get the date in 2013-01-23 format. Can anyone please tell me how to compare date in my table with curdate() function.

Comment: you should change your database field type as date, then you can compare your date data to table data

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate, `SELECT CURDATE() + 0`

Comment: @Dale: It is the module that created that table in expressionengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURDATE()` function returns both format `2008-06-13` and `20080613`

You should use like following:

```
WHERE date_column = CURDATE() + 0
```

**Document:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Answer (score 2):

simply do a

```
... WHERE CAST(dateformat(now(),'%Y%m%d') AS int)=datcol
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a format to the current date:

```
WHERE datecol <= dateformat(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the **INT** to **varchar** by using CAST function
and then convert the **varchar** into **date** using **STR_TO_DATE** function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

you can compare like as :

```
$tableDate = '20130123';
$curDate = '2013-01-23';
$curDate = str_replace('-','', $curDate);
if($curDate == $tableDate) {
   echo "Matched";
} else {
   echo "Not Matched";
}
```